# Get records that have all sub records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called medicine and an associated sub table called Medication_symptoms

**Medicine**

```
MediId, Name
1,      MedA
2,      MedB
3,      MedC
```

**Medication_symptoms**

```
MedSympId, Medicine (MedId),     Symptom (symptomId)
1,         MedA (1),             Symptom A (1)
2,         MedA (1),             Symptom B (2)
3,         MedB (2),             Symptom B (2)
4,         MedB (2),             Symptom C (3)
5,         MedC (3),             Symptom D
```

I have another table called Patient and Patient_Symptoms

**Patient**

```
PatientId, Name
1,         Patient A
2,         Patient B
3,         Patient C
4,         Patient D
```

**Patient_Symptom**

```
PatientSymptomId, PatientId,     SymptomId
1,                Patient A(1),  Symptom A (1)
2,                Patient A(1),  Symptom B (2)
3,                Patient B(2),  Symptom B (2)
4,                Patient B(2),  Symptom D (4)
5,                Patient D(4),  Symptom D (4)
```

Given the above info, I need to get the medication that matches all symptoms of a patient: (I would be pulling the info by each patient 1 by 1)

```
Patient A - Med A (as he has symptom a and b and Med is for symptom A and B)
Patient B - None! (as he has symptoms b and d and there is no medicine for symptoms B and D)
Patient D - Med C (as med C is for symptom D only and Patient D has only symptom D)
```

Note **Symptoms** is a separate table:

**Symptom**

```
Symptom Id, Name
1,          Symptom A
2,          Symptom B
3,          Symptom C
4,          Symptom D
5,          Symptom E
```

What is such a query called?

Note: I have made up this example. In what I am doing I have a record A, with a set of attributes (where the attributes are stored as rows of records against Record A). I need to match that record A with another record C, that has the exact same set of attributes as A. (Making sense?)

You can create the tables and some sample data using the script at http://pastebin.com/kaqdtHf3

Comment: Kindly include the column names in your sample data.

Comment: Do you mind explaining the logic for how you determine the medication for a patient?  For instance, I don't see how `Patient B` results in `None!`.

Comment: Does the match have to be 100% exact?  For instance, what if patient `X` has symptoms `A` and `B`.  And medication `Y` is defined for symptoms `A`, `B` ***and `C`***, should medication `Y` be returned?

Comment: _What is such a query called?_ In terms of relational algebra what you're looking for is division (you're dividing the set of symptoms a patient has with the set of symptoms a medicine treats to get the medicines that can treat all of the symptoms). There's a good article by Celko on the subject with some different solutions: [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: @jpw, the article on relational division - awesome! thanks!

Comment: I have posted a script to create the db and data at http://pastebin.com/kaqdtHf3

Comment: I found another article that answers the exact same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556790/return-parent-records-with-child-records-equaling-specific-values-and-where-tota

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine `not exists` and `full join … null` to select all medicines that do not - not - (double negative) have a treatment for symptom that a  patient has - therefore the medicine does have all treatments

```
select * from medicine m
where not exists (
    select 1 from patient_symptom ps 
    full join medication_symptoms ms on ps.SymptomId = ms.SymptomId
          and ps.PatientId = :myPatientIdHere
          and ms.MedId = m.MedId
    where (ms.SymptomId is null or ps.symptomId is null)
)
```

Another way using conditional aggregation to exclude any medicines that do not treat a symptom of a patient

```
select ms.MedId
from patient_symptom ps
join medication_symptoms ms on ps.SymptomId = ms.SymptomId
where ps.patientId = :myPatientIdHere
group by ms.MedId, ps.patientId
having count(ms.symptomId) = (select count(*) from patient_symptom ps2 
                                where ps2.patientId = ps.patientId)
and count(ms.symptomId) = (select count(*) from medication_symptoms ms2 
                                where ms2.MedId = ms.MedId)
```

**Update**

If you use a `full join`, you can use conditional aggregation to make sure that there are no null values on either side of the full join to make sure there's a 1:1 match.

```
select t1.MedId
from (
  select * from 
  patient_symptom ps
  cross join medicine m
  where patientId = :myPatientId
) t1
full join medication_symptoms ms on t1.SymptomId = ms.SymptomId
      and t1.MediId = ms.MediId
group by t1.MedId
having count(case when t1.SymptomId is null or ms.SymptomId is null then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: When I have a Med A for Symptoms A,B,C and Patient A with Symptoms A and B, it still returns Med A (dont want it to). A full outer join didnt seem to help. Also, the  2nd query didnt work with the following error - Column 'patient_symptom.PatientId' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I have no idea how you are doing this as fast as you are!  #RESPECT

Comment: The first query still causes me to get Med A. But the 2nd query is doing exactly what I want it to do. What kind of a query is this called? (so that I can read up more about it)

Comment: @RajRao It's an aggregate query with a subquery in its having clause. I don't think there is a specific name for it. I'll look into why the 1st query isn't working, it seems it should

Comment: I was able to get the first query to work when I changed it to: select * from medicine m
where not exists (
    select 1 from patient_symptom ps 
    full join medication_symptom ms on ps.SymptomId = ms.SymptomId and ps.PatientId = :myPatientIdHere
    where ms.MedicineId = m.Id and (ms.SymptomId is null or ps.symptomId is null)  
)

Comment: seem like the problem had to with where the clause regarding the patient Id was being put. It works when its with the ON clause. Doesnt work if its in the where.
full join medication_symptom ms on ps.SymptomId = ms.SymptomId and ps.PatientId = :myPatientIdHere

Comment: that makes sense, if there's a medicine symptom that does not have a corresponding patient symptom then we still want to return that row in order for ``not exists` to return false

Comment: Your first query still has a problem. if you have a medicine that works for all symptoms, then the query doesnt return the right value. I found only the following works:   select * from medicine m
where not exists (
    select 1 from 
 (select ms.symptomId from Medication_Symptom ms where ms.medicineId = m.id)ms1
 full join 
 (select ps.SymptomId from Patient_Symptom ps where ps.PatientId = 7 )ps1
 on ps1.SymptomId = ms1.SymptomId
 where (ps1.SymptomId is null or ms1.symptomId is null))

Comment: @RajRao pls see update, I think all conditions except the null check need to be moved to the `on` clause

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple answers that FuzzyTree posted. Here is his first query with all the changes that I had to make to get it to work. His query #2 works too.

```
SELECT *
FROM medicine m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM (
            SELECT ms.symptomId
            FROM Medication_Symptoms ms
            WHERE ms.medId = m.medid
            ) ms1
        FULL JOIN (
            SELECT ps.SymptomId
            FROM Patient_Symptom ps
            WHERE ps.PatientId = 7
            ) ps1 ON ps1.SymptomId = ms1.SymptomId
        WHERE (
                ps1.SymptomId IS NULL
                OR ms1.symptomId IS NULL
                )
        )
```

**The following query we have found to be more faster than the one above** (this was found by a co-worker and looking at wall clock times and the query plans, this one was quicker)

```
select m.Name
from Medicine m
where m.Id in (
    select ms.MedicineId
    from       Medication_Symptom ms
    inner join (select SymptomId
        from Patient_Symptom
        where PatientId = 7)      ps on ps.SymptomId = ms.SymptomId
    group by ms.MedicineId
    having count(*) = (select count(SymptomId)
        from Patient_Symptom
        where PatientId = 7)
    intersect
    select ms.MedicineId
    from Medication_Symptom ms
    group by ms.MedicineId
    having count(*) = (select count(SymptomId)
        from Patient_Symptom
        where PatientId = 7)
    )
```

finally, this query returns the data for all patients:

```
select po.Name, m.Name
from Medicine m, patient po
where m.Id in (
    select ms.MedicineId
    from       Medication_Symptom ms
    inner join (select SymptomId
        from Patient_Symptom
        where PatientId = po.Id)      ps on ps.SymptomId = ms.SymptomId
    group by ms.MedicineId
    having count(*) = (select count(SymptomId)
        from Patient_Symptom
        where PatientId = po.Id)
    intersect
    select ms.MedicineId
    from Medication_Symptom ms
    group by ms.MedicineId
    having count(*) = (select count(SymptomId)
        from Patient_Symptom
        where PatientId = po.Id)
    )
```